# Is there any way to create an array of files in a model in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I am creating a web app for cloud storage where user can create folders and upload files. I want to create a model for files like:

```
class upload(models.Model):
    files = # array of files which I don't know how to create
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I will be thankful if anyone suggests me how to do so or tell me any other efficient way to upload files and use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create another model (e.g. `UploadFragment`) and bind it with a foreign key relation to your `Upload` model.

```
class Upload(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class UploadFragment(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField()
    upload = models.ForeignKey(Upload, related_name="files", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: And what if I want to show all the files for a user in his profile? I would have to use `objects.filter()` which will query through all the files in the database. Isn't it a bit inefficient?

Comment: That's exactly how a select query works so it's pretty optimized at the database level. If you're seeing poor performance, then it's time to do query profiling and optimization

Comment: `class upload(models.Model):`
        `files = models.FileField()`
        `title = models.CharField(max_length = 30)`
        `user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)` 
will there be any problem if I create my model like this because I find the way mentioned above a bit confusing

Comment: well - this will work - based on your example I thought that one upload consists out of many files ;) You should call it `file` instead of `files` as it will be one, not many. But from the point of view of user there will be many uploads - each with one file.